# Is this a correct place to use exec/eval?

Tags: python, eval

So I keep hearing everyone saying "don't use exec, don't use eval, etc." But I was wondering if it's correct to use under this cirumstance.

I have multiple functions that do the same thing for different operating systems:

```
def doCoolStuff_Windows():
    # do cool stuff here, windows edition

def doCoolStuff_Darwin():
    # do cool stuff here, mac edition
```

Then I have one master function that detects the user's operating system and runs the correct function for it.

I decided instead of doing a giant if-else thing, it would be easier to use exec like this:

```
def doCoolStuff():
    system = platform.system()
    exec "doCoolStuff_%s()" % system
```

Is this a correct usage of exec? Or is there a more correct way to accomplish the same task?

Thanks

Comment: Use an if statement instead of exec for that example

Comment: Briefly: no, it is not a good usage of `exec`. Use branches or a mapping.

Comment: exec is fine there, it's only a problem when you are dealing with unsanitized user input

Comment: @Natecat - No, `exec` is not fine. It's totally unnecessary. There's no reason to introduce such a thing when a dictionary would suffice perfectly well.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 this topic and the one you marked as duplicate have completely different questions, but the same answer. does that still make it a duplicate? If so that isn't really fair on my part as I didn't know that "variable variables" existed in another language, didn't know that's what they were called, and didn't know to look that up.

Comment: Yes, it is still a duplicate. You had an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You aren't being unfairly penalized because you aren't being penalized at all. This question will now help others who are wondering whether they should use `exec` in this situation. :)

Comment: but people seem to be downvoting it because it's a duplicate :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not trying to start a flame war, but... No, imo that's not really a valid use of `exec` when there's a really easy alternative and very rarely is there ever a good reason to use `eval`.

You can simply setup a dispatch dict like so, or just use an if statement which would be simpler here.

```
 dispatch = {'Windows': doCoolStuff_Windows, 'Darwin': doCoolStuff_Darwin}
 def doCoolStuff():
     system = platform.system()
     if system in dispatch:
         dispatch[system]()
```

Comment: It is less readable though, I would actually argue that exec is a better solution here

Comment: @Natecat - No, I would say that the dictionary solution is far superior. It could even be improved by doing away with the `if` and simply doing `dispatch.get(system, lambda: None)()`.

Comment: @Natecat I would think most people would prefer this version if for no other reason than it is 100% explicit about what operating systems are currently included in the list. Everything you need to know is right there. With the exec version, you have to go looking for it.

Comment: Note that big dispatch dicts can be made much more readable by splitting the entries into separate lines.

Comment: I'd never heard of a dispatch dict before, and it works really well. I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks guys!

Comment: Pressing "dd" on my exec statement. Wow that felt good.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Depending on the actual code it may be desirable to not even bother using `if` or `get`, since if `doCoolStuff` is called on an unsupported platform we probably _don't_ want it to fail silently. Instead, we can catch the `KeyError` (perhaps transmuting it into an `AssertionError`) and print a helpful error message. OTOH, it may be possible to provide a simple `doCoolStuff_default`, which can be supplied as the default arg to `get`.